# ShopifySharp orderService.ListAsync() method doesn't return already fulfilled Orders. What is the way to get them?

Tags: shopifysharp

ShopifySharp orderService.ListAsync() method doesn't return already fulfilled Orders. What is the way to get them?

var filter = new OrderListFilter() { Ids = new List { 5354837999702 } };
var shopifyOrders = service.ListAsync(filter).Result;

I was expatiating the order would show up even though its fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the orders already fulfilled, in filter we'll have to use Status = "any".

Example:
var filter = new OrderListFilter() { Ids = new List { 5354837999702 } ,Status = "any"};

var shopifyOrders = service.ListAsync(filter).Result;